# Wildcards in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to select specific lines of data in awk. I want data the starts with FWA20120629, then has 4 numbers I don't care about, then has and 18,19,or 20, and then two more characters I don't care about. I've tried this:

```
awk '{if ($2 ~ /FWA20120629....[18-20]../) print $2,$5,$6}' ...
```

and

```
awk '{if ($2 ~ /FWA20120629????[18-20]??/) print $2,$5,$6}' ...
```

an example line that would fit this criteria is

> FWA2012062903001800

I'm clearly missing something, and I'm not familiar enough with awk to figure it out.

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...]` are *character* classes in regular expressions. `[18-20]` doesn't match all numbers between 18 and 20, it matches the character 1, all characters between 8 and 2 (which is meaningless), and the character 0.

Try `(18|19|20)` instead if that's what you want.

Comment: I changed the 18-20 to 18|19|20 like you said, now my first line of output data is `FWA2012062900000500`,which still isn't right

Comment: Did you include the `()`?

Comment: @rootusercyclone and in awk you'd write `'$2 ~ /FWA20120629....(18|19|20)../ {print $2,$5,$6}'`, not `'{if ($2 ~ /FWA20120629....(18|19|20)../) print $2,$5,$6}'` since awk already has builtin condition/action sections. You probably want to anchor the regexp too: `/^FWA20120629....(18|19|20)..$/` and you may want to only look for digits, not any char, and use RE intervals for convenience: `/^FWA20120629[0-9]{4}(18|19|20)[0-9]{2}$/`.

Comment: Another question for everyone: How would I strip column $2 from the first 11 characters and just output the last 4 to the file? Example: instead of outputting the whole `FWA2012062913001800`, it would just output `1800`?